# 404 page based on language

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have site structured like this
root/en/
root/it/
To manage the languages I use

```
$supported_languages = array(
    'English'  => 'EN',
    'Italiano' => 'IT',
);
```

With the two language files containing the defines, and most of it works fine, but the 404 page which shows only one language based on the htaccess I use (example.com/it/the-wrong-page). Needless to say I don't know how to properly write the htaccess rule. I tried the following two different ones.

This shows only Italian (obviously)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /it\x2F.*/">
    ErrorDocument 404 /404-error-it.php
</If>
```

This shows only English

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /it\x2F.*/">
    ErrorDocument 404 /404-error-it.php
</If>
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /en\x2F.*/">
    ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php
</If>
```

I guess the last directive overwrites the first one. How would I do to have the 404 showed in the language according to the sub (i.e. /en and /it)?

For completion of info I also have a sub that is not under the language subs (root/sub).

Comment: Use a single script, and inside that check what the originally requested URL was (the parts can be found in $_SERVER), determine the language from that, and respond with the corresponding content …?

Comment: To use some sort of script I had thought of, but really wouldn't even know where to start, and how to implement it. I you have a sample you'd like to share, I'd be happy to play with it.